# Building your own docker images of SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose

I'm not sure if it is a bug or just me being stupid but here is the case.

I want to build my image based on [StandaloneChromeDebug](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome-debug). Following the [Wiki](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/wiki/Building-your-own-images):

1. Pull the repo.
2. Generate image:

```
$ make standalone_chrome_debug
```

3. Build the Dockerfile to insure that no errors arise:

```
$ docker build --no-cache etc/docker-selenium/StandaloneChromeDebug/
```

4. Set up my image to the docker-compose.yml like:

```
selenium-hub:
        container_name: selenium-hub
        build: ./etc/docker-selenium/StandaloneChromeDebug/
        volumes:
            - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
        ports:
            - "4444:4444"
            - "5900:5900"
        environment:
           - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
           - HUB_PORT=4444
```

And... nothing. The container is running (no errros) but Selenium doesn't work, container log is empty, `/opt/` folder is empty. What am i doing wrong? How to debug the thing?

Comment: can you run the image? `docker run <YOUR_IMAGE>` ?

Comment: In https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium it says to do  GRID_DEBUG=true to enable debugging

Comment: @Chandan i've try to put `GRID_DEBUG=true` to `docker-compose.yml` file to `environment` section, but it doesn't make any difference. I guess I have some low-level issue before container actually starts working.

Comment: @LinPy i would say yes. It works

Comment: so what do you mean by Selenium doesn't work ? what is the output of `docker ps`after running `compose` ?

Comment: Actually your first question caught me by surprise. To execute `docker run` i made `docker build` with the tag. And it worked. After that i made replacement in `docker-compose.yml`:  `build: ./etc/docker-selenium/StandaloneChromeDebug/` replaced with `image: mytag`. And it worked again. So, basically it works. But i still don't understand why it doesn't work based on `build: ./path/to/Dockerfile/`

Comment: I think the path is wrong or you need to set the context to build . iam not sure

Comment: @LinPy it doesn't look so. The path is correct because you can't start container with wrong path. The context looks the same. I'm in charge of all environment values and I switched them in every possible way for the last 3 hours.

Comment: when you say selenium doesn't work, what happens exactly?

Comment: @TarunLalwani well, container is running. But the log of container is empty and all the files related to selenium are not there: /opt/ folder is totally empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Path is wrong, use `build: /etc/docker-selenium/StandaloneChromeDebug/` without `.`
If you try to cd to `./etc/docker-selenium/StandaloneChromeDebug/`, you will get an error.

```
version: "3.5"
services:
   selenium-hub:
        container_name: selenium-hub
        build: /etc/docker-selenium/StandaloneChromeDebug/
        volumes:
            - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
        ports:
            - "4444:4444"
            - "5900:5900"
        environment:
           - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
           - HUB_PORT=4444
```

Exapmle:
[image]

Comment: It is really funny to see it working for someone else :) Thank you for your afford. In my case log stops on the line `Attaching to selenium-hub` both with `./` in the path and without it.

Answer (score -1):

I feel you are using "build" tag in your compose file rather than "image". Please use "image" tag instead and see if that runs your image correctly.

Also can you please show how you are launching your docker services and what the output is?

[Reference to build command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)